# how will i use border layout in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have following code i want that window opened uses `Ext.layout.BorderLayout` and also on the left side of the window has `Ext.tree.TreePanel`... I tried it but when I use `BorderLayout` the page does not open? Can anyone help me with this?

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  var window = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 100,
    width: 100
  });
  
  window.show();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And where is not-woking code with BorderLayout? Post it too.

Comment: did you put an item with region: 'center' inside the window... because that is mandatory for border layout ...

Comment: no if i use this statement instead of above code for window. >> window = new Ext.Window({layout: 'border'}).show() , this does not do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [official example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/window/layout.html) showing a window with a BorderLayout. It's not enough just to add `layout:'border'` you have to add panels to the layout container and also configure the layout regions properly.

E.g.:

```
        var window = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
            title: 'Hello',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                region: 'west',
                title: 'Sidebar',
                width: 200,
                split: true,
                collapsible: true,
                floatable: false
            }, {
                region: 'center',
                html: 'Some content'
            }]
        });
```

Comment: it gives an error on items when i try this code: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.2a/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.2a/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function(){

Comment: var window = Ext.create('Ext.Window', { 
            title: 'Hello', 
            width: 100, 
            height: 100, 
            layout: 'border', 
            items: [{ 
                region: 'west', 
                title: 'Sidebar', 
                width: 200, 
                split: true, 
                collapsible: true, 
                floatable: false 
            }, { 
                region: 'center', 
                html: 'Some content' 
            }] 
        }); 

    })
</script>

Answer (score 3):

Some addition to bmoeskau's answer. I recomend you to not use JavaScript reserved words like window, document, number etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply give your window a `border` layout and set the `region`s for the immediate children. Each child will have its own layout and child items.

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
      expanded: true,
      children: [{
        text: "Wake up",
        leaf: true
      }, {
        text: "Go to Work",
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
          text: "Eat Lunch",
          leaf: true
        }, {
          text: "Finish Report",
          leaf: true
        }]
      }, {
        text: "Go to Sleep",
        leaf: true
      }]
    }
  });

  var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    title: 'Hello World',
    width: 480,
    height: 220,
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
      layout: 'fit',
      region: 'west',
      title: 'Tasks',
      width: 180,
      split: true,
      collapsible: true,
      floatable: false,
      items: [{
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        store: treeStore,
        rootVisible: false,
      }]
    }, {
      layout: 'fit',
      region: 'center',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'textarea',
        value: new Lorem().createText(6, Lorem.TYPE.SENTENCE),
        flex: 1
      }]
    }]
  });

  myWindow.show();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/f/loremjs/master/lorem.js"></script>
```